# More space in »\hangindent« items

Tags: lists

There are some extra lists of attachments, which are implemented using a definition of `\hangindent` I copied somewhere (ahem, without understanding it).

I just need more space after (see MWE below, »1.2«, »1.2.3.4«) the numbers. I'd like to align the beginning of text. Unfortunately I can't redefine the whole machinery how the lists are produced.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter % unless in a .cls or .sty file
\newcommand*{\hangfrom}[1]{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#1}}%
  \hangindent \wd\@tempboxa
  \noindent\box\@tempboxa}
\makeatother  % unless in a .cls or .sty file


\begin{document}

\hangfrom{1.2.3.4} some text

\hangfrom{1.2} some more text


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the extra space to the box you are creating and also remove every space after printing the box:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter % unless in a .cls or .sty file
\newcommand*{\hangfrom}[1]{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#1\hspace{2em}}}%
  \hangindent \wd\@tempboxa
  \noindent\box\@tempboxa\ignorespaces}
\makeatother  % unless in a .cls or .sty file

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\hangfrom{1.2.3.4} some text

\hangfrom{1.2} \blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the indent should be same for all *items* you could use a `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter % unless in a .cls or .sty file
\newcommand*{\hangfrom}[1]{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\makebox[4em][l]{#1\hfill}}%
  \hangindent \wd\@tempboxa
  \noindent\box\@tempboxa\ignorespaces}
\makeatother  % unless in a .cls or .sty file

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\hangfrom{1.2.3.4} some text

\hangfrom{1.2} \blindtext


\end{document}
```

[image]

However IMHO it would better to use a real list, e.g., with [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). It should be easy to add `\begin{…}` before the list and `\end{…}` after it, and replace `\hangfrom{…}` by `\item[…]`.

Comment: I choose your second solution, thank you! Yes, rewriting the commands for the attachments would be better. But I'd have to carefully protect the commands, because things have to be written into an aux-file. Not today...